# How do I transform the data in this SQL Table into a specific format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have a table called `T1` (extract below) which contains around 100,000 records.

```
Property    Room    Season   Datefrom    Dateto      Name
ABC LTD     DLX       P     01-01-2018  01-03-2018   John
XYZ LTD     SUP       P     01-01-2018  01-04-2018   Alan
```

I need a SQL query that will transform the data from this table `T1` and give me the following output:

```
Property    Room    Season     Date       Name
ABC LTD     DLX        P    01-01-2018    John
ABC LTD     DLX        P    01-02-2018    John
ABC LTD     DLX        P    01-03-2018    John
XYZ LTD     SUP        P    01-01-2018    Alan
XYZ LTD     SUP        P    01-02-2018    Alan
XYZ LTD     SUP        P    01-03-2018    Alan
XYZ LTD     SUP        P    01-04-2018    Alan
```

How can I do this with a T-SQL query?

Comment: Use a Calendar Table (for example [Bones of SQL - The Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/)) and then `JOIN` onto it using your `DateTo` and `DateFrom` and `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Things like _explaining_ what you want to accomplish and what you've tried are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tally table or a calendar table is the way to solve this. Recursive solutions are usually slower and can cause other errors. This answer is a lot like the answer from @JohnCappelletti, I included a more reliable tally table and rejection of invalid intervals.

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
(
  [Property] varchar(50),
  [Room] varchar(50),
  [Season] char(1),
  [Datefrom] date,
  [Dateto] date,
  [Name] varchar(50)
)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES
 ('ABC LTD','DLX','P','01-01-2018','01-03-2018','John')
,('XYZ LTD','SUP','P','01-01-2018','01-04-2018','Alan')

;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT 1 FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d)
SELECT
  Property,
  Room,
  Season,
  b.Date,
  Name
FROM @YourTable a
CROSS APPLY
( 
  SELECT top(datediff(d,Datefrom,case when DateTo >= DateFrom
             then dateadd(d, 1, DateTo) else DateFrom end))
    DATEADD(d,row_number()over(order by 1/0)-1, DateFrom) Date
  FROM tally
) b
```

If dateto is before datefrom, the row will not be included.

Comment: Excellent! Transformed around 115,000 rows into 2,830,000 rows in 33 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is a **CROSS APPLY** in concert with an ad-hoc **Tally Table**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Property] varchar(50),[Room] varchar(50),[Season] varchar(50),[Datefrom] varchar(50),[Dateto] date,[Name] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('ABC LTD','DLX','P','01-01-2018','01-03-2018','John')
,('XYZ LTD','SUP','P','01-01-2018','01-04-2018','Alan')


Select Property
      ,Room
      ,Season
      ,Date = B.D
      ,Name
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,Datefrom,IsNull([DateTo],DateFrom))+1) 
                       D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),DateFrom) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1  --,master..spt_values << remove comment of span can be > 6 years 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: John, this was timely and I really liked it, I just used it to help another op over on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908324/how-can-i-compare-two-tables-without-relationship-1-table-with-40k-records-and/48909999#48909999

Comment: I did up vote, but it appears the op on this thread went with the tally table and the case statement answer.

Comment: @Random_User Sorry I had it in my little head that it was your question

Answer (score 0):

If there are not very many days, then this is a good opportunity to learn about recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select Property, Room, Season, datefrom as dte, Name, dateto
      from t
      union all
      select Property, Room, Season, dateadd(day, 1, dte), Name, dateto
      from cte 
      where dte < dateto
     )
select *
from cte;
```

By default this will work for up to 100 days.  You can use `option (maxrecursion 0)` so it works for any number.

For performance, a numbers table is faster, but recursive CTEs have surprisingly reasonable performance under many circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. By 'work for up to 100 days', do you mean that the difference between the Datefrom and Dateto for each record should not exceed 100 days?

Comment: @user3115933 . . . Yes, unless you use the max recursion option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Property    NVARCHAR(255),
    Room    NVARCHAR(255),
    Season   NVARCHAR(255),
    Datefrom    DATE,
    Dateto      DATE,
    Name NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('ABC LTD','DLX','P','01-01-2018','01-03-2018','John'),
('XYZ LTD','SUP','P','01-01-2018','01-05-2018','Alan')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       Property,
       Room,
       Season,
       MyDate = Datefrom,
       Name,
       Dateto
       FROM @T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       Property,
       Room,
       Season,
       MyDate = DATEADD(D,1,MyDate),
       Name,
       Dateto
       FROM CTE
          WHERE MyDate < Dateto

)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY Property
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same or similar to other answers. I think Gordon was first. I am practicing with recursive CTE.

```
declare @t table (Property varchar(20), Room varchar(20), Season varchar(20), Datefrom datetime, Dateto datetime, Name varchar(20));
insert into @t values 
       ('ABC LTD','DLX','P','01-01-2018','01-03-2018','John')
     , ('XYZ LTD','SUP','P','01-01-2018','01-05-2018','Alan');

with cte as 
( select Property, Room, Season, Datefrom as [Date], Dateto, Name
  from @t 
  union all
  select Property, Room, Season, DATEADD(day, 1, [date]), Dateto, Name 
  from cte 
  where [date] < Dateto
)

select Property, Room, Season, casT([Date] as date) as [Date], Name 
from cte 
order by property, [date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a date range table.

```
declare @t table (Property varchar(20), Room varchar(20), Season varchar(20), DateFrom date, DateTo date, Name varchar(20));
insert into @t values 
       ('ABC LTD','DLX','P','01-01-2018','01-03-2018','John')
     , ('XYZ LTD','SUP','P','01-01-2018','01-05-2018','Alan');

declare @dateRange table (dt date primary key);
declare @minDate date = (select min(datefrom) from @t);
declare @maxDate date = (select max(dateto)   from @t);
with dates as 
(
     select @minDate as dt 
     union all 
     select DATEADD(day, 1, dt) 
     from dates 
     where dt < @maxDate
)
insert into @dateRange 
select dt from dates option (maxrecursion 10000);

select t.Property, t.Room, t.Season, d.dt as [Date], t.Name
  from @t t 
  join @dateRange d
    on d.dt >= t.DateFrom 
   and d.dt <= t.DateTo
 order by t.Property, t.Room, d.dt;
```